# What do the acronyms mean after the slash in the Firefox dictionary?

Tags: firefox, dictionary

What do these capital letters mean after the `/` character in the `en-US.dic` file found in the `\Firefox\Dictionaries` folder?

For example:

```
collectivism/M
collectivist/MS
collectivity
collectivization/M
collectivize/GDS
collector/MS
colleen/SM
college/SM
collegial
```

What does `M` or `MS` or `GDS`, etc. mean?  I'm sure there's documentation online somewhere, but I'm not having much luck finding it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The letter identifiers refer to [affixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affix) listed in the corresponding `.aff` file. This prevents the need to list every form of every word in the `.dic` file. See "[Understanding the Affix File Format](http://lingucomponent.openoffice.org/affix.readme)" for further information.

The same format is used by the [MySpell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySpell) spell checker.

Answer (score 3):

After searching on this myself I finally found this page with a good explanation.

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/how-tos/editing-the-spell-checking-dictionaries

> Each rule is in the .aff file for that language. The rules come in two
>   flavors: SFX for suffixes, and PFX for prefixes. Each line begins with
>   PFX/SFX and then the rule letter identifier (the ones that follow the
>   word in the dictionary file:
>
> PFX [rule_letter_identifier] [combineable_flag]
>   [number_of_rule_lines_that_follow]
>
> You can normally ignore the combinable flag, it is Y or N depending on
>   whether it can be combined with other rules. Then there are some
>   number of lines (indicated by the )
>   that list different possibilities for how this rule applies in
>   different situations. It looks like this:
>
> PFX [rule_letter_identifier] [number_of_letters_to_delete]
>   [what_to_add] [when_to_add_it]
>
> For example:
>
> - SFX B Y 3
> - SFX B   0     able       [^aeiou]
> - SFX B   0     able       ee
> - SFX B   e     able       [^aeiou]e
>
> If "B" is one of the letters following a word, then this is one of the
>   rules that can apply. There are three possibilities that can happen
>   (because there are three lines). Only one will apply:
>
> able is added to the end when the end of the word is "not" (indicated
>   by "^") one of the letters in the set (indicated by "[ ]") of letters
>   a, e, i, o, and u. For example, question → questionable able is added
>   to the end when the end of the word is "ee". For example, agree →
>   agreeable. able is added to the end when the end of the word is not a
>   vowel ("[^aeiou]") followed by an "e". The letter "e" is stripped (the
>   column before able). For example, excite → excitable.
>
> PFX rules are the same, but apply at the beginning of the word instead
>   for prefixes.

Comment: Can you summarize the information at the link within your answer in case the link goes dead?

Comment: Each letter in the .dic file following the slash is a name of a rule in the .aff file. Read more at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40294335/1860089