# Firefox spellchecker for English

Tags: firefox, spell-check

I'm using Firefox with this spell checker: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/united-states-english-spellche/

It proposes to write **Up vote** instead of **upvote** and similar with many other prefixes.

Are there spell checkers for Firefox which work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have upvote as a possibility you could add it to the English.dic file which is used by the application.

Comment: I just found http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20457/upvote-vs-up-vote-vs-up-vote

Comment: I stand corrected.  +1 for you :-)  Was my answer any use?

Comment: I didn't try it yet. First I have to find out the correct spelling. And I guess there are different Spell Checker for Firefox. I'll wait a bit, before trying to modify one myself. What happens in case of updates etc.

Comment: +1 OK I found the files and noted that they are ASCII files. A link explaning the file format would be great.

Comment: @bernd_k forget the english.aff file that is the affix file.  The english.dic is the dictionary file.  So, add "upvote" to that file should update the spellchecker. I updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: Did you get it working?  Cool.  Have a good wkd.

Comment: Yes, and knowing the file extensions I found http://superuser.com/questions/235487/what-do-the-acronyms-mean-after-the-slash-in-the-firefox-dictionary