# How do I add new words to Firefox dictionary suggestion list?

Tags: firefox, dictionary

I know how to add new words to Firefox dictionary, but how do I add them to the auto-suggest list when a word is misspelled?

I'm an electrical engineering student and many many terms associated with EE aren't in the dictionary, so I need to add them by hand. So when I type microcontroller, I don't get the red underline anymore, but when I type microcontrrler, I don't get microcontroller as a suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

To add a word to Firefox's main dictionary, where it will also be used for both spelling checks and suggested edits, do this:

1. Go to the [Firefox installation directory](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Installation_directory#Finding_the_installation_directory). (Nominally: `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\`)
2. From there, the dictionary is in the `dictionaries` subfolder.
   Select the file for the language you use.  Typically: `en-US.dic`.
3. Make a backup copy of the file -- `en-US.dic.bak`, etc.
4. Edit the file with any text editor.  To add words, just append them; you don't need to alphabetize.

   **Notes about editing:**

   1. One word per line.
   2. Words and flags are case-sensitive.

      1. If the entry is for `Abigail`, `abigail` will not be allowed.
      2. However, all-lowercase entries allow some capitalization. For example, if the entry is: "zonked" (no quotes):

         ```
         Word        Allowed?    Suggested?
         -------     --------    ----------
         zonked          y           na
         zonkedq         n         zonked
         Zonked          y           na
         ZONKED          y           na
         ZONKEDq         n         Zonked
         ZONked          n         Zonked
         ```
   3. You will notice a <kbd>/</kbd>, followed by uppercase letters, following some entries.   These are [affix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affix) identifiers for the affixes stored in `en-US.aff` (or the appropriate file for your language).

      See [this answer for more about how Firefox uses affixes](https://superuser.com/questions/235487/what-do-the-acronyms-mean-after-the-slash-in-the-firefox-dictionary/235511#235511).   See [the Lingucomponent Project](http://lingucomponent.openoffice.org/) for even more gruesome detail.

      For now, you probably want to know the <kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>M</kbd> affix-labels.

      1. <kbd>S</kbd> smartly handles most plural forms.  For example, the entry `microcontroller/S` will allow and suggest "microcontroller" and "microcontrollers".
      2. <kbd>M</kbd> smartly handles most possessive forms.  For example, the entry `microcontroller/SM` will allow and suggest "microcontroller's", in addition to the plural forms.
   4. While in the dictionary, delete the lines for `whilst` and `withe`, they have no business in there! (^_^)
   5. I like to keep the file in Unix format (as shipped).  It saves a little memory -- and hopefully speed -- over PC format.
5. Restart Firefox for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the "misspelled" (the correctly spelled version) word, and select "Add to Dictionary." Or maybe you've done this, and this doesn't update the suggestion list as you desire?

Comment: It doesn't update the suggestion list.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, you can add your own words in

```
~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/<profilename>.default/persdict.dat
```

Just add one word per line.
To open the file you can use the finder, press Shift + Command + G and enter this path

```
~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/
```