# Editting en_US.dic file with custom words

Tags: dictionary

I want to manually add words to the en_US.dic library. When I open the file in a text editor I can add words as needed, but I do not understand what some of the syntax or attributes are. I spent an hour looking for the answers but was unable to find what I was looking for.

Here is an example of what I am trying to understand.

```
logarithm/MS  
logbook/MS  
loge/SMNX  
logged/U  
loggerhead/SM  
logger/SM  
loggia/SM  
logging/MS  
logicality/MS  
logicalness/M  
logical/SPY  
logician/SM  
logic/SM  
login/S
```

After each of the above words is an "/" followed by one or more capital letters, '/SM' or '/U' or '/SPY' etc. and I don't know what they mean and if I need to use them when I add words manually myself.

Answer (score 1):

I found this page with a pretty good explanation.

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/how-tos/editing-the-spell-checking-dictionaries

Also, this is a duplicate of [What do the acronyms mean after the slash in the Firefox dictionary?](https://superuser.com/questions/235487/what-do-the-acronyms-mean-after-the-slash-in-the-firefox-dictionary)

However, I'm modifying the .dic and .aff files from Pidgin spell checker instead of those from Firefox. (Maybe the same files?)